# Create or Maintain a single CHANGELOG from multiple Git repositories

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I tried to look up any examples or GitHub actions if there is a way to generate or maintain a single CHANGELOG.md file for all GitHub repositories (say more than 10).

I would like to know if this can be achieved through any automation work (through Python) if possible. Any help (any ideas, reference examples, etc.) would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have tried a small Python script to achieve this:

```
import requests

# GitHub access token
access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

# List of repositories you want to collect changelog data from
repositories = ["owner/repo1", "owner/repo2"]

# Initialize an empty changelog
changelog = ""

# Loop through repositories
for repo in repositories:
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo}/releases"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"token {access_token}"}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        releases = response.json()
        for release in releases:
            # Format the release data as needed
            changelog += f"## {repo} {release['tag_name']}\n"
            changelog += release['body'] + "\n\n"

# Write the consolidated changelog to a file
with open("changelog.md", "w") as changelog_file:
    changelog_file.write(changelog)
```

Comment: What do you mean "all GitHub repositories"?  Does this mean you have several independent Git repositories and you want to have one file (`CHANGELOG.md`) be automatically maintained across them?

Comment: Yes, correct! I have multiple independent repositories.

Comment: If so, how does the file get updated, could one repo be considered the authoritative copy and other ones be updated when it changes, or should changes in one be pushed out too all copies?  Might be worth thinking about merging multiple repos into one, lots of little repos are kind of annoying and the monorepo movement is worth checking put

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in the same direction where one repo would be the "authority" which would trigger some automation possibly using GitHub action or Python Github API. The automation script would be given a list of repositories for which I would create a changelog to get rid of any tiny (playground or test ) repositories.

Comment: What's the purpose of maintaining this file?  is it to include in released versions of the code?  I'm still not sure why you'd want to do to this automatically, seems to be working around something else and it would be easier to fix that other thing which would let the standard tools work together